# how to upload a package to launchpad ?? please help step by step?

Tags: application-development

I got this error while uploading.
apport is set to ignore crashes in this version of bzr.
bzr: ERROR: pycurl.error: (28, 'SSL connection timeout at 297257')

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bzrlib/commands.py", line 924, in exception_to_return_code
    return the_callable(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bzrlib/commands.py", line 1124, in run_bzr
    ret = run(*run_argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bzrlib/commands.py", line 689, in run_argv_aliases
    return self.run(**all_cmd_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bzrlib/commands.py", line 711, in run
    return self._operation.run_simple(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bzrlib/cleanup.py", line 135, in run_simple
    self.cleanups, self.func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bzrlib/cleanup.py", line 165, in _do_with_cleanups
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bzrlib/plugins/launchpad/__init__.py", line 277, in run
    account.check_lp_login(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bzrlib/plugins/launchpad/account.py", line 106, in check_lp_login
    data = _transport.get_bytes('~%s/+sshkeys' % username)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bzrlib/transport/__init__.py", line 610, in get_bytes
    f = self.get(relpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bzrlib/transport/http/__init__.py", line 126, in get
    code, response_file = self._get(relpath, None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bzrlib/transport/http/_pycurl.py", line 171, in _get
    return self._get_full(relpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bzrlib/transport/http/_pycurl.py", line 206, in _get_full
    self._curl_perform(curl, header)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bzrlib/transport/http/_pycurl.py", line 375, in _curl_perform
    curl.perform()
error: (28, 'SSL connection timeout at 297257')

bzr 2.3.4 on python 2.7.1 (Linux-2.6.38-8-generic-i686-with-
    Ubuntu-11.04-natty)
arguments: ['/usr/bin/bzr', 'launchpad-login', 'nvnvenki']
plugins: bash_completion[2.3.4], bzrtools[2.3.1], launchpad[2.3.4],
    netrc_credential_store[2.3.4], news_merge[2.3.4]
encoding: 'UTF-8', fsenc: 'UTF-8', lang: 'en_US.UTF-8'

*** Bazaar has encountered an internal error.  This probably indicates a
    bug in Bazaar.  You can help us fix it by filing a bug report at
        https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr/+filebug
    including this traceback and a description of the problem.
Launchpad connection is ok
No Launchpad project set, leave blank to abort.
Launchpad project name:
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're expecting an answer for exactly, but the problem in your comment appears to be a simple SSL connection timeout when doing `bzr launchpad-login` on your computer. Perhaps there is an issue with your Internet connection, ISP, or you are behind a proxy which might break SSL connections. It is hard to say, but the only real advice I can suggest is to try again.